# Litestar GET function blocks OpenAI

Tags: python, litestar

When I transfer function to litestar, it suddenly stops OpenAI from returning a completion. I can print to console every declared variable except answer:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from litestar import Controller, Litestar, get
from litestar.types import ControllerRouterHandler

import os
import pinecone
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai


__all__ = (
    "index",
    "support",
)

load_dotenv()

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

@get("/")
async def index() -> str:
    return "Тестовый запрос выполнен. Чтобы получить ответ, воспользуйтесь командой /support/{вопрос%20вопрос}."

@get("/support/{question:str}")
async def get_answer(question: str) -> str:
    
    pinecone.init(
        api_key=os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY"),
        environment=os.environ.get('PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT'),
    )

    index_name = os.environ.get('PINECONE_INDEX_NAME')

    k = 2

    docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embeddings)
    res = docsearch.similarity_search_with_score(question, k=k)

    prompt = f'''
    Use text below to compile an answer:
    {[x for x in res]}
    '''

    completion = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens = 1000
    )

    answer = completion.choices[0].text
    return {"answer": answer}


routes: list[ControllerRouterHandler] = [
    get_answer
]

app = Litestar([index, get_answer])
```

Though bare OpenAI script works fine:

```
import os
import pinecone
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai
    
load_dotenv()

# Подготовим эмбеддинги
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

pinecone.init(
    api_key=os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY"),
    environment=os.environ.get('PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT'),
)

index_name = os.environ.get('PINECONE_INDEX_NAME')

query = input("Enter your question: ")
k = 2

docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embeddings)
res = docsearch.similarity_search_with_score(query, k=k)

prompt = f'''
Use text below to compile an answer:
{[x for x in res]}
'''


completion = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",
  prompt=prompt,
  max_tokens = 1000
)

print(completion.choices[0].text)
```

pip freeze:

```
litestar==2.2.1
openai==0.27.8
pinecone-client==2.2.2
```

Litestar keeps showing 500 Internal Server Error without details. `index()` works fine.
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using Litestar that has the same problem you would  face.

```py
from litestar import Litestar, get

@get()
async def get_answer() -> str:
    return {'hello': 'world'}

app = Litestar([get_answer])
```

Making a GET request to `localhost:8000` returns

```
{"status_code":500,"detail":"Internal Server Error"}
```

If you turn on debug mode like so `app = Litestar([get_answer], debug=True)` the following error is shown when you make the same request.

```
500: Unable to serialize response content
```

This is because you have mentioned the return type as `str` in `async def get_answer(question: str) -> str:` but in your actual code you are returning a `dict`. Litestar uses the return type of the function to serialize the data. Converting a `str` to `dict` fails.

In your example `index` works fine because the return type and the actual return value are the same `str`.

The fix is to use the correct return type for `get_answer`. `dict[str, str]` or even plain `dict` is enough.

```
from litestar import Litestar, get

@get()
async def get_answer() -> dict[str, str]:
    return {'hello': 'world'}

app = Litestar([get_answer])
```

If you are on 3.8, you can use `typing.Dict` instead of `dict`.

```py
from typing import Dict
from litestar import Litestar, get

@get()
async def get_answer() -> Dict:
    return {'hello': 'world'}

app = Litestar([get_answer])
```

PS:

> Though bare OpenAI script works fine:

This is why I removed the OpenAI parts and only focused on the litestar ones. If you have an error in that you would still get a 500 error, you will have to fix that separately.